# 2D Motion vectors - calculate location of object at a given time

Tags: swift, algorithm, vector, geometry, game-physics

I am having problems understanding 2D motion vectors when moving certain objects at a given time. My knowledge of linear algebra is limited and I really don't know the exact search terms to look for, so I wanted to know whether anybody could help me or at least hint me in the right direction.

My problem looks like this:

I have two points, a startPoint, and an endPoint in space. They have each a specific location, denoted as (x_1, x_2) and (y_1, y_2) respectively. Both of these points have a time attached to it, named t_startPoint or t_endPoint, respectively. I now want to find out, for a given currentTime (= basically any point in time that is in between t_startPoint and t_endPoint), where exactly would a new point N be positioned on the connection line between those two points. I know the description is not trivial and that’s why I also added an image describing what I would like to do:

[image]

So far, this is what I have as my algorithm:

func update(_ time: Int64) {

```
    let t_startPoint: Int64 = 1
    let position_startPoint: = (1.0, 1.0)

    let t_endPoint: Int64 = 5
    let position_endPoint: Vector = (4.0, 5.0) 

    let currentTime = 3

    let duration = t_endPoint - t_startPoint

    let x = position_startPoint.x + ((position_endPoint.x - position_startPoint.x) / Float(duration)) * (Float(currentTime - t_startPoint))
    let y = position_startPoint.y + ((position_endPoint.y - position_startPoint.y) / Float(duration)) * (Float(currentTime - t_startPoint))

    //
```

However, no matter what I do, my objects keep overshooting, erratically moving back and forth, and I don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The term you are looking for is interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constant velocity moving there is relation:

```
 (t-t1) / (t2-t1) = (x-x1) / (x2-x1) 
 x = x1 + (x2-t1) * (t-t1) / (t2-t1)
```

so your expresiion looks right. Check:

```
1 + (4-1) * (3-1) / (5-1) = 1 + 3 * 2 / 4 = 2.5 - exact middle, OK
```